# Отлов запросов с помощью Wireshark

Tags: http, сеть, post, get, wireshark

Имеется вопрос: Как я могу отловить все POST и GET запросы с помощью Wireshark? Ставил фильтры `http.request.method == "POST"` и прочие, но когда мониторил трафик во время использование сайта (отправлял сообщение, фильтровал друзей по критериям), ни одного POST или GET запроса так и не поймал. Разве отправка сообщение не является POST запросом? Тоже самое мне сказал Хром, когда я посмотрел все запросы через Network в F12.

```
Request URL: https://api.prime.date/chat/send/text
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.18.12.108:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Но в Wireshark я ничего не увидел. Кто-то знает, что делать в таком случае?

Comment: ты пытаешься фильтруешь http-трафик, а соединяешься по https... снифать https — нетривиальная задача: надо как-то получить сессионные ключи (например экспортировать из браузера) и уже с их помощью расшифровывать записанный трафик, а уже потом фильтровать...

Comment: Есть ли какая-то ссылка на статью или что-то вроде того? Я новенький в этом деле, ваш ответ ничего мне не сказал.

Comment: первая ссылка из гугла по запросу «wireshark https»: https://habr.com/ru/company/billing/blog/261301/